# Add column to format file bcp utility

Tags: sql-server, bcp

```
select row_number() over(order by column), *
from table a
```

I used the query above to extract the data into bcp file but the format file picks on select * from table a,
how do I create a format file based on the query above?
or can add it to the fmt file using python?

I have tried adding a line with the  new column name to the format file but was unsucessful

Comment: Have you tried specifying an alias for the ROW_NUMBER() function (e.g. `row_number() over(order by column) AS row_num`)?